# How to make my php program run in linux all the time?

Tags: php, linux, progress

I finished a program with ZMQ, built a PHP Socket Program, and in order to accept some Client requests. I must be sure that this Server Program run in linux all the time.

I run this Program like this:`php /app/server.php`.

And, the Terminal shows my output statement like `waiting for client connecting...`, at this time, I can't use my Terminal to do others things, unless I `Ctrl + c` to exit this program.

I want to let it automatical run in linux background like a progress. And the Program may die when `PHP Error`, I have to restart this program manually.

I also want to it can restart self when error happened.

How to do that? Thank U first:)

Comment: while it can be done with php, php is not designed for this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [System_Daemon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon/) PEAR package.  I've used it several times and find that it works well.

Comment: Umm....Could U give me some guides? I checked that [offical documentation](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon), I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Screen" program. you can use the following parameters to de-attach it from the current terminal and have your program running inside it.

```
screen -d -m php /app/server.php
```

also to have it autostart at boot time, add the above line to

> /etc/rc.local

Answer (score 0):

Use the & symbol at the end of the command to run the program in the background, like so:
php /app/server.php &

You can put the above command in /etc/rc.local so that it starts automatically when the system boots.

If you program produces output, you might want send it to a log file instead of STDOUT.

Comment: And the program may be interupted with some PHP Error, how to let system know it and restart the program?